# How to Inherit properties in css?

Tags: css

How to Inherit properties in css? I have a class:

```
.drop-shadow-red {
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    padding: 0.4vh 0.7vh;
    background: url(../images/redInvert.png) no-repeat center left;
    background-position: 8px 50%;
    background-size: 2vh;
    background-color: rgba(250, 210, 50, 0.9);
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -mox-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0.1vh 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
    z-index: 99;
    animation: blinkBorder .6s step-end infinite alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

And I want now to create another class `.drop-shadow-yellow` that has all properties like `.drop-shadow-red` but the only change is that `background-color` is `yellow`. How to optimize the code to not duplicate so much code, like:

```
.drop-shadow-yellow {
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    padding: 0.4vh 0.7vh;
    background: url(../images/redInvert.png) no-repeat center left;
    background-position: 8px 50%;
    background-size: 2vh;
    background-color: yellow; /* <-------------------------------------- */
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -mox-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0.1vh 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
    z-index: 99;
    animation: blinkBorder .6s step-end infinite alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Comment: Did you search first, then asking the question?

Comment: yes i did but, I think I don't ask the right question in google :)

Comment: Read best practices, like https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6741

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a class with all properties but `background-color` and name it for example `drop-shadow`.

Now you just create additional classes like `red-bg` and add `background-color: red` and pass the `drop-shadow` class as well as the background class to an object.

Example:

CSS:

```
.drop-shadow {
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    padding: 0.4vh 0.7vh;
    background: url(../images/redInvert.png) no-repeat center left;
    background-position: 8px 50%;
    background-size: 2vh;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -mox-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) , 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0.1vh 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
    z-index: 99;
    animation: blinkBorder .6s step-end infinite alternate;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.red-bg{
    background-color: rgba(250, 210, 50, 0.9);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="drop-shadow red-bg">Foo Bar!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only one property do it inline style and take everything else  from the css.